# nnetar giving different output each time

Tags: r, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting

I am using nnetar package for time series forecasting in R.But each time when I run the model, I am getting different output. i guess this is related to different random weight initialization at each time, but I don't know how to set it as constant.

```
ts=nnetar(Time_Series,P=3,lambda = 0,decay=0.001,maxit=150)
fs = forecast(ts, h=12)
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the random seed before you call `nnetar` and you will get the same random initialization each time.

```
set.seed(12345)
ts=nnetar(Time_Series,P=3,lambda = 0,decay=0.001,maxit=150)
fs = forecast(ts, h=12)
```